# Make an element in array explode

Tags: php

How to make an element array inside an array explode again.
I have an array like this

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($pks);
```

The Result.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2017-04-15||KMTC_HOCHIMINH
    [1] => 2017-04-15||OOCL_NAGOYA
)
```

I expected like this,

```
Array
(
    [record] => 
       [1] 2017-04-15
       [2] KMTC_HOCHIMINH
    [record] => 
       [1] 2017-04-15
       [2] OOCL_NAGOYA
)
```

What keys on php to process array like this.
Please advise.

**UPDATE**
How about this .

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2017-04-15
        [vessel] => KMTC_HOCHIMINH
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2017-04-15
        [vessel] => OOCL_NAGOYA
    )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_walk()` (or just `foreach` if you want):

```
array_walk($pks, function(&$a) {
    $a = array_combine(['date', 'vessel'], explode('||', $a));
});
```

Foreach method:

```
foreach($pks as $k => $v) {
    $pks[$k] = array_combine(['date', 'vessel'], explode('||', $v));
}
```

However, the key of each array won't be `record`, since it's impossible to have the same key multiple times.

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2017-04-15
            [vessel] => KMTC_HOCHIMINH
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2017-04-15
            [vessel] => OOCL_NAGOYA
        )

)
```

Bonus method because I like messing with arrays:

```
$pks = array_map('explode', array_fill(0, count($pks), '||'), $pks);
```

Comment: Thanks mate, huge fans. Please see my updated question.

Comment: @FadlyDzil edited the `array_walk()` and `foreach` methods to produce the expected output. If my answer fixes your problem, please mark it as such.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, check the **[live demo](https://eval.in/800730)**

```
foreach($pks as $k => $v) {
    $values = explode('||', $v);
    $result[] = array_combine(range(1, count($values)), $values);

    //added
    $res[] = array_combine(['date', 'vessel'], $values) ;

}
```

result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => 2017-04-15
            [2] => KMTC_HOCHIMINH
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => 2017-04-15
            [2] => OOCL_NAGOYA
        )

)
```

Comment: @FadlyDzil check it now